# Is it quicker to create custom set before using RANK function

Tags: ssas, mdx

This runs ok:

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Measures].[Players_Rank] AS 
        RANK(
            [Player].[Player].CurrentMember,
            NONEMPTY(
                [Player].[Player].members,
                [Measures].[Score]),
            [Measures].[Score]
            )
```

But this runs a lot quicker:

```
WITH 
    SET X AS
        NONEMPTY(
            [Player].[Player].members,
            [Measures].[Score])
    MEMBER [Measures].[Players_Rank] AS 
        RANK(
            [Player].[Player].CurrentMember,
            X,
            [Measures].[Score]
            )
```

By seperating out the `NONEMPTY` set and calculating it before hitting the `RANK` function we get a performance gain - why?

Referring to the reference for the RANK function on MSDN A similar approach is used in here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144726.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a detailed explanation from one of the developers of Analysis Services here: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2006/03/14/ranking-in-mdx.aspx

Basically, your first query re-builds the set for each cell that needs to show the rank, while the second solution builds the set once, and caches it for all cells that use the ranking member.

Comment: +1 very useful link. Think I'll look out for a cheap copy of the [book Mosha co-authored](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Fast-Track-MDX-Server-2000/dp/1846281741)

Comment: @whytheq Please be aware that this book seems to be for AS 2000, and there were many changes since then. In fact, AS 2005 was a more or less complete re-write of the whole software.

Comment: ....but how old is his blog? (shame he's moved to Bing...). Tried to make a small change to your search script but not working - wonder why? (me not using the OR operator correctly - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240881/adding-or-into-the-filter-function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240881/adding-or-into-the-filter-function))