# Adding OR into the FILTER function

Tags: ssas, mdx

We've got the following thanks to @FrankPI in this **[SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044594/search-allmembers-of-user-hierarchy-for-corresponding-set-return-a-related-mem)**

```
WITH 
   MEMBER [Measures].[LevelName] AS
       [Employee].[Employee Department].CurrentMember.Level.Name
   MEMBER [Measures].[LevelNumber] AS
       [Employee].[Employee Department].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal
   MEMBER [Measures].[MemName] AS
       [Employee].[Employee Department].CurrentMember.Name
   SET [Set_TargetEmp] AS
        {
        FILTER(
            [Employee Department].AllMembers,
                (
                InStr(
                    1, 
                    [Employee].[Employee Department].currentmember.name, 
                    "WC4") <> 0
                ) 
            )
        }
SELECT
    {
    [Measures].[MemName], 
    [Measures].[LevelName],
    [Measures].[LevelNumber] 
    } ON 0,
    Hierarchize(
        Generate([Set_TargetEmp] as e,
            Ascendants(e.Current)
            +
            Descendants(e.Current, e.Current.Level, SELF_AND_AFTER)
        )
    )
    ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

I want to make one small change but the new member (Reuben H. D'sa) who is key 53, does not appear in the result set. Why?

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Measures].[LevelName] AS
        [Employee].[Employee Department].CurrentMember.Level.Name
    MEMBER [Measures].[LevelNumber] AS
        [Employee].[Employee Department].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal
    MEMBER [Measures].[MemName] AS
        [Employee].[Employee Department].CurrentMember.Name
    SET [Set_TargetEmp] AS
        {
        FILTER(
            [Employee Department].AllMembers,
                (
                InStr(
                    1, 
                    [Employee].[Employee Department].currentmember.name, 
                    "David P. Hamilton") <> 0
                ) 
            or
            [Employee].[Employee Department].currentmember.member_key = 53 //<<<<<<new bit
            )
        }
SELECT
    {
    [Measures].[MemName], 
    [Measures].[LevelName],
    [Measures].[LevelNumber] 
    } ON 0,
    Hierarchize(
        Generate([Set_TargetEmp] as e,
            Ascendants(e.Current)
            +
            Descendants(e.Current, e.Current.Level, SELF_AND_AFTER)
        )
    )
    ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `currentmember.member_key = 53` does not return any matching result. I tried `currentmember.Properties("Key0", typed) = 53`, and that returned both employees.

See [the documentation on the `Properties` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144821.aspx) and [the documentation on intrinsic properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145528.aspx) (sroll down to "Non-Context Sensitive Member Properties") for details.

Comment: maybe I should have used `IS` instead of `=` ....will try that instead. This is strange syntax Frank `.Properties("Key0", typed)` you got any further references to help me understand it?

Comment: I do not think `IS` would help here, as it is for member identity, having a member on both sides of the `IS`. But you use strings and numbers here. I did not try, but maybe `= "53"` would have worked as well. I would think `member_key` returns a string.

Comment: (+1 shame you field isn't t-sql Frank - think your rep would be 50k rather than 5k then!....glad you're on here as MDX answers are hard to find....I'm gonna hit the green tick now: 5,000 fireworks show starts)